# How do I make an indicator variable based upon what happened first?

Tags: r

Using R I am attempting to create an indicator variable based upon which of the two indicators in the linked data table "afdcwvr" or "tanfimp" occurred first for a given fips code (in other words, in which column did a "1" appear first for a give st_fips). How would I go about implementing the process?

[Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8p9r33sg3ndcwct/FSP_State_FYear_ProblemSet3.csv?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `library(data.table)`

```
#read data
dt <- fread('FSP_State_FYear_ProblemSet3.csv')

#find indexes of events
res <- dt[, list(i1 = which(tanfimp == 1)[1], i2 = which(afdcwvr == 1)[1]), by = st_fips]

#finding answer
res[, first := pmin(i1, i2, na.rm = TRUE)]
res[i1 == first & !is.na(i1), ans := 1]
res[is.na(ans), ans := 2]
```

So `ans` is 1 if first 1 is in `tanfimp` and 2 otherwise.